# Reference request: Prequantization of canonical transformations and Lie group action

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-representation-theory, quantization

Hello to MathoverFlow community

I have some seemingly technical questions on applications of geometric quantisation to Lie group representation theory.
We shall start by giving background definitions. We follow [1].
Let $(M,\omega)$ be a quantizable symplectic manifold. Then there exists a Hermitian line bundle $B\to M$ and a connection $\nabla$ on $B$ with curvature $\hbar^{-1}\omega$. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the Hilbert space of square-integrable global sections $s\colon M\to B$. Let $\widehat{f}$ be a linear operator in $\mathcal{H}$ corresponding to $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ and is given by
$$
\widehat{f}(s)=-i\hbar\nabla_{X_f}s+fs,
$$
where $X_f$ is a vector field such that $X_f\lrcorner\omega+df=0$.
Let $V_f$ be the vector field on $B$ given in a local trivialisation by 
$$
V_f=X_f+\hbar^{-1}L\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi},
$$
where $z=re^{i\phi}$ is the coordinate on the fibre of $B$ and
$$
\tag{2}
L=X_f\lrcorner\theta-f
$$
is the Lagrangian of $f$. 
Let $\xi_t$ and $\rho_t$ denote the flow of $V_f$ and $X_f$ respectively. The flow $\xi_t$ induces a linear 'pull-back' action $s\to \widehat{\rho}_ts$ on the sections s of $B$ where
$$
\xi_t(\widehat{\rho}_ts(m))=s(\rho_tm).
$$
In a local trivialisation, $s$ and $\widehat{\rho}_ts$ are represented by complex functions $\psi$ and $\widehat{\rho}_t\psi$ where
$$
\tag{1}
\widehat{\rho}_t\psi(m)=\psi(\rho_tm)\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int\limits^{t}_0 Ld s\right).
$$
The integration is along the integral curve of $X_f$ = the curve $\rho_s(m),0\leq s\leq t$.

Now, let $G$ be a connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. We fix $f\in \mathfrak{g}^*$ and make $G$ into a symplectic manifold by 
$$
\omega_f(R_A,R_B)=\frac12f\left([A,B]\right),
$$
where $R_A$ and $R_B$ is the right-invariant vector field generated by $A,B\in\mathfrak{g}$. Let $M$ be the symplectic reduction of the characteristic foliation of $(G,\omega_f)$ spanned by the right-invariant vector fields $R_A$, i.e.
$$
M=\{Hg\}_{g\in G},\quad H=G_f,
$$
where $G_f=\{g\in G\colon \mathrm{Ad}_gf=f\}$ is the stabiliser of $f$.

Let $\chi_f$ be the character corresponding to $f$. The integrality condition on $f$ is that the function
$$
\chi_f(h)=\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\int\limits^h_e \theta_f\right)
$$
should be a single-valued function on $H=G_f$. When this condition holds Kostant showed in [2] that the sections holomorphic line bundle over $G/G_f$ are identified with functions $\psi\colon G\to \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
\psi(hg)=\chi_f(h)\psi(g)
$$
for every $g\in G$ and $h\in H$.

**Question 1**: How one can rewrite formula (1) only in Lie-grop theoretic form, i.e. expressing all the quantities by Lie group and Lie algebra datum only.

My possible answers:

**Answer 1**: Using that $R_f\lrcorner\theta_f=\frac12f$, we get 
$$
L=\frac12f-f=-\frac12f.
$$
Then we fix time the flows at time $t=1$ and get from (1)
$$
\widehat{\rho_1}\psi(m)=e^{-i\int\limits f}\psi(e^{f}m).
$$

[1] N. Woodhouse. Geometric quantization. The Clarendon Press, Oxford University Press, New York, 1980. Oxford Mathematical Monographs.

[2] B. Kostant. Quantization and unitary representations. In Lectures in modern analysis and applications III, pages 87–208. Springer, 1970.

Comment: Ask in http://math.stackexchange.com/ . It is not really research question in the level MO

Comment: Hi, Hassan Jolany. I am sorry if this question is too obvious. Could you please then help me understand how to rewrite formula (1) above on Lie groups?

Comment: I don't think your formula makes the Lie group $G$ into a symplectic manifold, even if $G$ is compact semisimple (and if $G$ is commutative, $\omega_f$ is identically zero). In fact, that is impossible in this level of generality: for one thing, symplectic manifolds are necessarily even-dimensional, but Lie groups are not.

Comment: However, you *can* get a symplectic manifold in this way: namely, this formula defines (one half multiple of) the canonical symplectic form on the coadjoint orbit of $f$, which is naturally identified with the homogeneous space  $G/G_f$